# Why the requirement of the GCD of the lengths of all circuits in the graph being one?

Tags: random-process, information-theory, random, stochastic, ergodic

I am reading [A Mathematical Theory of Communication](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf). The second requirement of an ergodic process confuses me (emphasis mine):

> All the examples of artificial languages given above are ergodic. This
>   property is related to the structure of the corresponding graph. If
>   the graph has the following two properties the corresponding process
>   will be ergodic:
>
> 1. The graph does not consist of two isolated parts $A$ and $B$ such that it is impossible to go from junction points in part $A$ to
>      junction points in part $B$ along lines of the graph in the direction
>      of arrows and also impossible to go from junctions in part $B$ to
>      junctions in part $A$.
> 2. A closed series of lines in the graph with all arrows on the lines pointing in the same orientation will be called a “circuit.” The
>      “length” of a circuit is the number of lines in it. Thus in Fig. 5
>      series BEBES is a circuit of length 5. **The second property required
>      is that the greatest common divisor of the lengths of all circuits in
>      the graph be one.**

The author later elaborates

> If the first condition is satisfied but the second one violated by
>   having the greatest common divisor equal to $d > 1$, the sequences
>   have a certain type of periodic structure. The various sequences fall
>   into $d$ different classes which are statistically the same apart from a
>   shift of the origin (i.e., which letter in the sequence is called
>   letter 1). By a shift of from $0$ up to $d - 1$ any sequence can be
>   made statistically equivalent to any other. A simple example with $d =2$
>   is the following: There are three possible letters $a, b, c$. Letter
>   $a$ is followed with either $b$ or $c$ with probabilities
>   $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ respectively. Either $b$ or $c$ is
>   always followed by letter $a$. Thus a typical sequence is
>
> $$a\,b\,a\,c\,a\,c\,a\,c\,a\,b\,a\,c\,a\,b\,a\,b\,a\,c\,a\,c.$$
>
> This type of situation is not of much importance for our work.

But unfortunately, I still didn't get his point. Can you show me how to perform "a shift of from $0$ up to $d - 1$" to make two sequences statistically equivalent? In fact, the process already seems ergodic to me, but that's just my intuition, and I cannot justify my argument with rigorous reasoning.

In addition, what makes the above-mentioned process not of much importance in communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my understanding: the statistics of the source described in the paper depend on which character is produced first. If the first character is $a$, then one of the source properties is that letters in odd positions are always $a$. However, if the first letter is $b$ (in other words, a shift of $1$ in the circuit), then letters in odd positions can be either $b$ or $c$. This is what makes the source non-ergodic.

Note that the statistics when choosing $b$ as first letter and $c$ as first letter are exactly the same. In other words, there are $d=2$ different classes of sequences, and those in each class have the same statistics.

Regarding the importance of these sources: for one, Shannon's theorems depend on the source being ergodic. From a more practical standpoint (and this is purely my interpretation), non-ergodic sources are not good models for real-world processes; referring back to the example, no practical language produces repeated letters in a fixed periodic pattern.

I recommend reading "An Introduction to Information Theory: Symbols, Signals and Noise" by John R. Pierce, along with Shannon's paper. It explains many of the concepts in the paper in a very didactic manner. For example, it takes four pages to very clearly explain ergoidc sources, with nice examples.